# what does this Boxen output mean (sudo: ... command not found)?

Tags: macos, boxen

i'm getting output from `script/boxen` containing multiple lines of

```
sudo: Merge.app/Contents/Utilities:/Users/nrser/bin:/Users/nrser/dev/gh/nrser/nrser.env/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/nrser/dev/gh/nrser/rash/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: command not found
```

it's my first time with Boxen and Puppet, so i'm not sure if this is even an issue, but i'm can't really get much out of it.

full output:

```
imac:repo nrser$ ./script/boxen
Boxen is up-to-date.
Notice: Compiled catalog for imac.local in environment production in 2.37 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]/Gcc/Homebrew::Tap[homebrew/versions]/Homebrew_tap[homebrew/versions]/ensure: created
sudo: Merge.app/Contents/Utilities:/Users/nrser/bin:/Users/nrser/dev/gh/nrser/nrser.env/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/nrser/dev/gh/nrser/rash/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: command not found
sudo: Merge.app/Contents/Utilities:/Users/nrser/bin:/Users/nrser/dev/gh/nrser/nrser.env/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/nrser/dev/gh/nrser/rash/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: command not found
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[default]/Ruby::Version[1.9.3]/Ruby::Version[1.9.3-p545]/Ruby::Gem[bundler for 1.9.3-p545]/Rbenv_gem[bundler for 1.9.3-p545]/ensure: created
sudo: Merge.app/Contents/Utilities:/Users/nrser/bin:/Users/nrser/dev/gh/nrser/nrser.env/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/nrser/dev/gh/nrser/rash/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: command not found
sudo: Merge.app/Contents/Utilities:/Users/nrser/bin:/Users/nrser/dev/gh/nrser/nrser.env/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/nrser/dev/gh/nrser/rash/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: command not found
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[default]/Ruby::Version[2.0.0]/Ruby::Version[2.0.0-p451]/Ruby::Gem[bundler for 2.0.0-p451]/Rbenv_gem[bundler for 2.0.0-p451]/ensure: created
sudo: Merge.app/Contents/Utilities:/Users/nrser/bin:/Users/nrser/dev/gh/nrser/nrser.env/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/nrser/dev/gh/nrser/rash/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: command not found
sudo: Merge.app/Contents/Utilities:/Users/nrser/bin:/Users/nrser/dev/gh/nrser/nrser.env/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/nrser/dev/gh/nrser/rash/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: command not found
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[default]/Ruby::Version[2.1.0]/Ruby::Gem[bundler for 2.1.0]/Rbenv_gem[bundler for 2.1.0]/ensure: created
--> You haven't loaded Boxen's environment yet!
    To permanently fix this, source /opt/boxen/env.sh at the end
    of your shell's startup file.
```

on OS X 10.9.2 and fully merged with `our-boxen` master.

thanks in advance.

Comment: It means that a command used in `./script/boxen` cannot be found by the shell. This is likely because the command is not on the default path, there's a script that sets up the required environment variables (tells the shell where to look) in `/opt/boxen/env.sh`. If you execute that file does this problem go away?

Comment: @shuttle87 nope, sourcing `/opt/boxen/env.sh` before running `./script/boxen` did nothing but remove the `--> YOU haven't...` notice at the bottom. i get that it can't find a command, but it would be much more helpful if it at least mentioned the command it can't find, if not supplying the script call site, stacktrace, etc.. i'm not really sure where to start looking, or for what.

Answer (score 0):

seems to be caused by a space in a `PATH` element, see https://github.com/boxen/our-boxen/issues/611